# Getting the error "msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing" when running watir scripts after installing rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p136

Tags: ruby, watir

Installed rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p136 and ran the the following commands in the cmd prompt.

gem update --system
gem install watir.

The commands got executed successfully. But when i ran a ruby script with the following contents in it, i am getting the error "The program can't start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. " I tried reinstalling it multiple times, but no luck. 
              I google around and found the msvcrt-ruby18.dll file. But i don't know what i should do with it. Please help!

Contents of my ruby file:

---

require 'watir'
ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto('http://www.google.com')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, we need to register the autoit dll "AutoItX3.dll". In my machine the dll is located at C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rautomation-0.6.3\ext\AutoItX. So, you need to goto this folder in command prompt and execute "regsvr AutoItX3.dll". That fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

You've probably installed some binary gems that was built against msvcrt-ruby18.dll. The solution is to

1. install [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) so that you have an environment for building native code locally.
2. Uninstall the bad gem (which is causing this dialog when require'd)
3. Reinstall it, but force local compilation, i.e.

   gem install gemname --platform=ruby

Answer (score 1):

Did you try going to Ruby 1.8.6? I saw that recommended in the [Google Groups for Watir](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/b1005a8f653ab3cd#).

Also, I saw a reference to that in an issues about this in a [ruby forum thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/187997#955009), especially towards the bottom. If you are just getting started, then there probably isn't a need to support the newest version of Ruby, which has some issues with libraries compiled with previous versions of Ruby.

> You can define a gem to be targeted at one version of Ruby (using gem
>   spec required_ruby_version attribute), however, you can't generate a
>   binary gem that target both 1.8.x and 1.9.x series of Ruby.
>
> There are binary differences between 1.8.x and 1.9.x (different C-API,
>   different VM, etc) that made these pre-compiled extensions
>   incompatible.**

Apparently, Watir was built with 1.8.x. An alternative is to use Vapir, which is based on Watir but not backwards completely compatible because of changes in that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Don't download the ruby18 version if you like to run wxRuby. What you get is this:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/wxruby2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0011 p:-10361992 s:0034 b:0034 l:000033 d:000033 TOP   
c:0010 p:---- s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0013 s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 METHOD <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29
c:0008 p:0011 s:0023 b:0023 l:000022 d:000022 TOP    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/wx.rb:12
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 FINISH
c:0006 p:---- s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 CFUNC  :require
c:0005 p:0073 s:0014 b:0014 l:000010 d:000013 BLOCK  <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33
c:0004 p:0014 s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 METHOD <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29
c:0003 p:0011 s:0006 b:0006 l:00175c d:002234 EVAL   MinimalRuby.rb:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:00175c d:00175c TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
MinimalRuby.rb:1:in `<main>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/wx.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

the gem (wxruby 19) downloaded and installed just fine. Of course, that doesn't mean it will necessarily run.